# How does facebook opimizes and make 360 photos so fast?

Tags: facebook, 360-panorama

I'm very exited how facebook make 360 panorama photos so fast and performant when viewing on [facebook site](https://www.facebook.com/panoq/photos/a.1559147241047110.1073741829.1522809934680841/1556926151269219/?type=3&theater). I want to understand which technology/libraries they use to make something in my own site.

Is there any whitepapers about performance of 360 photos or give me some advises to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first trick with photos is always the best:  download while the user is doing interaction.   For example, you might see this interaction:

- Take photo
- Play around with filters, color, and cropping
- Click Send
- Be amazed at how fast it was!

What happened was:

- Take photo
  ** Start uploading photo data
- Play around with filters, color, and cropping
  ** Photo data finishes updating
- Click Send
  ** Send current filter settings up, which is a small packet of data
  ** Reapply the filters to large photo that was uploaded.  Tell you are done.

There are other tricks:

- Do the visible first.  For example, compute some downsampled results when a user touches a control.  You can visually 'apply' results when dragging, but really only and 320x180 image.  Similarly, a spreadsheet first updates the visible page and then worries about the future.
- Learn the hardware.   Applying a 4x4 simple transform matrix to rotate and stretch a 3D graphic takes about 16 million operations on 1000x1000 image.   Or 1 million using the right instructions.  Or 1 using the right video instructions.

It's a wonderful, large field.  Aiming at just one effect may get you more lot than trying to learn about the field and noticing what gives you the effect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know which technology/framework lies under the hood of viewing 360 panorama photos? I have a plans to make same feature on my site.

Comment: The phrase you are looking for is "stitching", or the recognition of edge artifacts for alignment.  I think FB uses a home grown version, but start with OpenCV (language agnostic) at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/stitching.html

Comment: Oh, and video is easier on the brain:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QapSxGnUWtY

Comment: "stitching" from what? We upload 360 panorama photo on facebook first and then it cuts it to stitch later?

Comment: Hi Erik.  This seems like you want a conversation.  Roughly, you are either using a 360 camera and stitching (see Bamboo renamed as iPix for the original realty market product) or you stitching less aligned photos.   If you are in Silicon Valley, we can have coffee.

Comment: your suggestion about coffee is exiting but unfortunately I'm not there :( I'm just interested in the following thing: say look at the following facebook post https://www.facebook.com/panoq/photos/a.1559147241047110.1073741829.1522809934680841/1556926151269219/?type=3&theater As you can see we this is WebGL technology. But how they create this? I've found, via dom inspector, that there is the following image https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.7935-8/13403211_1556926191269215_1158698172_n.jpg . Does they create webgl canvas based on this image?

Comment: Hi Erik.   Look me up your next trip to the valley.  Yes, it's stitching.  It looks like uses React to take the events of the mouse movement and stitch the new canvas from a series of transforms of clips of the individual images.  In this case, the images have been pre-stitched, meaning they are perfectly aligned and one just watches the canvas mouse events to redraw the canvas a series of svg transforms that update the canvas.  That is, they use SVG to blt onto the canvas.  SVG shows in the DOM.   You seem to just want a final package.  Good luck.

Comment: Yes I'm looking for a final package to make the same on my site. Ok, thanks for the answer and Good luck you too :))

Comment: Thank you.  For out the box, try kaideoscope.js or js-360.  I haven't used either.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/kaleidoscopejs, https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/360